# IIS rewrite rule is not working in Azure production

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I have website with multiple domains and i want them to have different robots.txt
I have rule for this so depends on domain request it will return different robots. This is workin beta slot but after deploy to production slot its not working.

```
<rule name="robots" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^robots.txt" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{HTTP_HOST}.robots.txt" />
        </rule>
```

If i am changing action type to redirect it seems to work because webbrowser redirects and is in stuck with to many redirects (Which make sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) mentioned that the server variable `REQUEST_URI` can be used to access the entire requested URL path, including the query string. Assuming that the URL for robots.txt is `https://<your-hostname-and-port>/robots.txt`, then you would get the string `/robots.txt` as an input via `REQUEST_URI`.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="robots" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/robots.txt" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{HTTP_HOST}.robots.txt"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

With the rule above, I could rewrite my URL and get the following result:

[image]

Changing the type of the rule action from Rewrite to Redirect, I could get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thats it :) i was struggling with that for few days but this as always stupid simple thing